# How to generate models with another model's primary key as the model name in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I am working on a django project where the website will let the user to register for an event and let them check in.

models.py contains:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    eventName = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True) # Event Name
    eventDescription = models.TextField() # About the Event
```

I want the program to generate more models with the eventName attribute row values from Event model.

Example:
Consider that Event model consists of the following row values:

1. CodeChef | CodeChef annual Event
2. GSOC | Google Summer Of Code

Then I want the following models to be automatically generated with some predefined attributes (number of attendees, EventStatus):

```
class CodeChef (models.Model):
   numAtendees = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   eventStatus = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class GSOC (models.Model):
   numAtendees = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   eventStatus = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Is it possible to auto generate the above models? If yes, then suggest a way to do the solution.

PS: I am a beginner to Django.

Comment: Welcome to SS. To registering events by users and yourself, why not using just one model with a name field? for example: `class GenralEvent` with `event_name` and `numAtendees`, and `eventStatus` attributes (fields)?

Comment: Yeah i thought of it. but i need to store the data in separate models for further processing.

Comment: But in this way also every process is simply possible just by filtering on the desired field. No limitation.  Creating different tables for each case of an entity is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Add them all in one model, create a ForeignKey to your `User` model if your Users Creating the events:

```
class GeneralEvent(models.Model):
    eventName = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True) # Event Name
    eventDescription = models.TextField() # About the Event
    numAtendees = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    eventStatus = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # You can also add a ForeignKey field to create connection to event owner user
```

now you can simply Retrieve on `id` field or filter on `User` (or any other field) to do your processing. for exmaple for `GSOC` event:

```
gsoc_events = GeneralEvent.objects.filter(eventName='GSOC')
```

The output will be a `queryset` of all `GSOC` events.

Hope this helps.